# Java Bytecode manipulation libraries

Tags: bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, javassist, bcel

I am starting to work on a project and for one of the tasks I need to analyze the source code in order to gather information about the classes and their methods. More specifically, for each method I need to know which internal attributes and external objects (references) it uses throughout the entire method body.

I discussed it with my supervisors and they think that Bytecode manipulation libraries is the way to go. I already looked at BCEL, ASM and Javassist but I'm not sure which one I need to use. Do they all provide access to the method body where I can see all the instructions and get the information I need?

Any advice would be appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you really “need to analyze the source code”, then libraries which allow to inspect the *bytecode* are not the way to go.

Otherwise, you really need to define your task precisely. Either, you are about to analyze classes, regardless of whether you will look at their source code or byte code, or you want to analyze source code and consider doing it by compiling first, followed by analyzing the compiled result. In the latter case, you have to compare the effort of both steps with alternative solution, which may, e.g. incorporate direct source code analysis.

Parsing byte code is rather easy, easier than analyzing source code, which is the reason why bytecode is produced prior to the execution of Java programs. To answer your concrete question, yes, all three libraries offer you a way to analyze the instructions and associated information. Which one is the best to fit your needs, is a question that is [beyond the scope of Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Whether analyzing the byte code helps, depends on your exact requirements. When it comes to field and method access, you may precisely get most of them using that approach. Only inlined compile-time constants lack their origins. When it comes to type use, you have to consider that not every source code artifact has an existing counterpart in the byte code, e.g. widening casts produce no actual code and and local variables usually don’t have a declared type (debugging information aside), but only an implied type which depends on how they are actually used. They also have no information about Generics, unless debugging information has been included.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I decided to go for analysing bytecode because as you said, it is much easier than having to analyse the source code. For now, my task is simply what I stated, check all methods of a specific class and return a list of variables used in that method. I'll take a closer look at three options. Thanks again.